# antd column chart: label value is displayed outside of chart

Tags: charts, antd

I have a fairly simple ant column chart, this is it:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Column } from "@ant-design/plots";

const DemoColumn = () => {
const data = [
{
  type: "Value 1",
  value: 315801
},
{
  type: "Value 2",
  value: 222095
},
{
  type: "Value 3",
  value: 10800
}
];

const config = {
data,
loading: data.length === 0,
xField: "type",
yField: "value",
seriesField: "type",
  yAxis: {
    label: {
      formatter: (v) => v
    }
  },
  xAxis: false,
  height: 200,
  autoFit: false,
  legend: {
    position: "bottom",
    flipPage: false
  },
  interactions: [
    {
      type: "element-active"
    }
  ],
  label: {
     position: "top",
     offsetY: 8,
     formatter: ({ value }) => value
   }
 };
 return <Column {...config} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<DemoColumn />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

The problem is, that the number of Value 1 is hanging off the chart. I tried setting the padding but this did not help, it acutally screwed the whole chart up?!?

[image]

Here is also a fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-microservice-gbrbm9?file=/index.js:0-929

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it myself by adding

```
appendPadding: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an **Open Bug** in AntD GitHub [[BUG] Label of column charts are being cut out if label position is set to 'top'](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-charts/issues/1372) officials for this issue. Some member of ant design team has given an answer as set `limitInPlot: true` in `config`. I tried that but didn't work.

I tried with adjusting `height` prop and `offsetY` in `lable` prop inside `config`. This is just tricky option for you to achieve what you want.

**Option 1** -

```
label: {
  position: "top",
  offsetY: 15, // change offset to this then value will not crop as before but just overlap with chart.
  formatter: ({ value }) => value
}
```

[image]

**Option 2** -

```
xAxis: false,
height: 750, // increase the chart height and it will show the value with a gap. But this will create a scroll. 
autoFit: false,
```

[image]

**Option 3** -

You can use mix of above two options with adjusting right values. This will get what you want without a scroll. below values got this result.

```
xAxis: false,
height: 500, // adjust height
autoFit: false,
legend: {
  position: "bottom",
  flipPage: false
},
interactions: [
  {
    type: "element-active"
  }
],
label: {
  position: "top",
  offsetY: 12, // adjust offset
  formatter: ({ value }) => value
}
```

[image]

This is the [sandboxcode](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-chart-column-issue-72827435-l09j73?file=/index.js).

Hope this will help to overcome your issue.

Comment: actually, your idea led me to a solution that I found here: https://g2plot.antv.vision/en/docs/api/plots/liquid Will answer my own question now. Big thanks though to you for pointing me in this direction!

Comment: Glad you found a solution and I've been able to point you that direction! Feel free to upvote if you feel it was useful to you.